# How do you prove the property that you can move limits in and out of continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

Suppose $$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L,$$ and if $g$ is continuous, then $$g\left(\lim_{x \to c} f(x)\right) = g(L) \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to c} g(f(x)) = g(L).$$ A popular application of this would be to take the logarithm of both sides and then move the logarithm inside the limit. How do you prove this property?

Comment: The question is strange. If $\lim_{x\to x}f(x)=L$, then $$g(\lim_{x\to c}f(x))=g(L)$$ holds for any function $g$. No need continuity. I guess you want to prove that if $g$ is continuous at $L$, then $$\lim_{x\to c}g(f(x))=g(L).$$ This is rather straightforward using the definition of the limit... Indeed, if $\varepsilon >0$, take $\delta >0$ s.t. $$|x-L|<\delta \implies 
 |g(x)-g(L)|<\varepsilon .$$ Now, take $\eta>0$ s.t. $$|x-L|<\eta\implies |f(x)-L|<\delta .$$ Then you are done since $$|x-L|<\eta\implies |f(x)-L|<\delta \implies |g(f(x))-g(L)|<\varepsilon .$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's straight from definition of continuous and limits.

Let $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = L$.  $g$ is continuous so for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ so that $|y-L| < \delta \implies |g(y) - g(L)| < \epsilon$.

But $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = L$ so for that $\delta$ then there is $\gamma > 0$ so that if $|x - c|< \gamma$ then $|f(x) - L| < \delta$ and therefore $|g(f(x)) - g(L)| = |g(f(x)) - g(\lim_{x\to c}f(x))| < \epsilon$.

So by definition.   $\lim_{x\to c} g(f(x)) = g(L)=g(\lim_{x\to c} f(x))$.

Comment: But $f$ does not have to have to be continuous for this property to hold?

Comment: Okay, but $\lim f(x) = L$.... I'll type up a better answer.

Comment: You say that $|f(x) - f(c)| = |f(x) - L|$, but if $c \notin \text{Dom}(f)$, then this is not true. But as far as I understand, $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L$ can exist even if $c \notin \text{Dom}(f)$

Comment: that was a remnant of the previous answer that I hadn't editted properly.  The same with the reference to $d$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$. By continuity at $L$, there exists $\eta>0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\eta \implies |g(f(x))-g(L)\rvert<\epsilon$. Since $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\eta$. Hence, $0<|x-c|<\delta \implies |g(f(x))-g(L)|<\epsilon$.

By definition,
$$
\lim_{x\to c} g(f(x))=g\left(\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\right)=g(L).
$$